# ansible-pull not finding playbook to run

Tags: git, yaml, ansible, ansible-pull

I am very new to ansible, about a few hours experience. I am currently trying to run an `ansible-pull` command and it isn't working the way I am expecting it to. I have a git repo with a .yml file. Inside the repo I just have the .yml and the README file.

The command I am running is:

`ansible-pull -d ./ansible_directory -U github.repo`

I am receiving an error that says the local.yml file does not exist. Which in turn is giving me an error that reads `ERROR! Could not find a playbook to run.`.

I am unsure of where/how to create a local.yml file. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I changed the name of my .yml file to local.yml and it fixed the first error, but it is still throwing the second error.

Comment: using ansible-pull may complicate things for you, especially since you are just getting started.  I suggest creating your Ansible code on the machine that you have Ansible. Then run 'ansible-playbook yourfile.yml' from whatever directly you are going to store your ansible code instead of pulling from an external repository, which is what Ansible-pull does.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ansible-pull -C <branch name> -U https://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git <file_name>.yml
```

Answer (score -1):

go through "README.md" and "pull.play" file in following repo.

  git clone https://github.com/harshad007/ansible_pull.git

do necessary changes with git repository **url** and **IP** addresses in hosts file

first run pull.play script as "ansible-playbook pull.play" if everything goes right then after few minutess check
/var/log/ansible-pull.log on "remote system".
Here, local.yml file from GitHub repository has executed.